# DotVVM Redirection

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, dotvvm

Hi I would like to ask what is the correct way for redirection from a command in dotVVM framework. I am trying to redirect to another page via Context.Redirect() function that actually works but I get an exception "DotVVM.Framework.Hosting.DotvvmInterruptRequestExecutionException" with additional information "Error in the application" that actually doesn't help and I would like to get rid of it, not just ignoring it. My current code is

**DotHTML**

```
<dot:Button Click="{command: Register()}" Text="Register" class="register-button" />
```

**cs**

```
public void Register()
{
    Context.Redirect("Register");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception is OK. DotVVM uses exceptions internally to perform the redirects - there is no other reasonable way to do that. 
Just hit F5 in Visual Studio and it will continue.

Answer (score 0):

RedirectToRoute is the new name in their API.

I notice that calling RedirectToRoute in an async command doesn't produce this behavior.